# Flutter Timer Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, time, timer

I implemented a Timer but it doesn't seem to be calling the callback() functions after the right duration, it starts by calling the callback after a few seconds and speeds up every time the callback is called.
Ex. 5 sec --> callback(), 4 sec --> callback(), 2 --> callback(), 0.3 sec --> callback () ...

I would like to have a timer that reduces the value of an int after each second.

Current code - ViewModel:

```
  void displayCountdown(Item item) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer _timer) => {
      if (lead.remainingTime >= 1) {
        item.remainingTime = item.remainingTime -= 1,
        notifyListeners(),
      }else {
        print('out of time'),
        _timer.cancel(),
        notifyListeners(),
      }
    });
  }
```

Code - View:

```
  ListTile _tile(Item item) {
    widget.model.displayCountdown(item);
    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: item.remainingTime);
    String countdown = '${duration.toString().split('.')[0]}';
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: item.author["avatarUrl"] == "" ? NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=3') : NetworkImage(lead.author["avatarUrl"]),
      ),
      title: Text(item.author["fullName"]),
      subtitle: Text(item.keywords.toString()),
      trailing: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [Text('$countdown', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey))],),
    );
  }
```

Comment: "it starts by calling the callback after a few seconds and speeds up every time the callback is called" ... Are you sure that you aren't creating multiple `Timer`s for the same `Item`s?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm not really used to flutter yet. Maybe it creates a new one every time I call `widget.model.displayCountdown(lead);` and therefore it accelerates it? The only place where I create a Timer is in displayCountdown().

Comment: Yes, every time you call `widget.model.displayCountdown()`, it will create a new periodic `Timer` object.  It won't affect existing `Timer`s, but you'll have more running than you expect, so you'll observe more callbacks being fired.  If your intention is to have one `Timer` per `Item`, I recommend that you maintain a `Map<Item, Timer>` so that you can avoid creating a new `Timer` if one already exists (or so that you can cancel existing ones).

Comment: Thanks, but I found an alternative x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't worked but I found an alternative that works.

First, I create a getter for my countdowns.
Second, when I get my items, I set each timer in my getter.
Third, I create my timers with my getter values.
Fourth, I call my getter at the index of the current tile in my view.

```
...
  List<int> get countDowns => _durations;
  List<int> _durations = [];

  List<Item> items = [];
...

  Future getItems() async {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);
    final response = await _api.getItems();
    if (response is SuccessState) {
      items = response.value;
      for (var item in items) {
        _durations.add(item.remainingTime);
      }
      displayCountdowns();
    } else if (response is ErrorState) {
      String error = response.msg;
      print('Error $error');
    } else {
      print('Error');
    }
    setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }
...
  void displayCountdowns() {
    for (var countDown in _durations) {
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) { 
        countDown -= 1000;
        _durations[0] = countDown;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    }
  }
```

Here is the code for the view:

```
...
var duration = Duration(milliseconds:widget.model.countDowns[index]);
...
  ListTile _tile(Lead lead, Duration duration) {
    String countdown = '${duration.toString().split('.')[0]}';
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: lead.author["avatarUrl"] == "" ? NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=3') : NetworkImage(lead.author["avatarUrl"]),
      ),
      title: leadTitle(lead.author["fullName"]),
      subtitle: leadSubtitle(lead.keywords.toString()),
      trailing: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [Text('$countdown', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.grey))],),
    );
  }
```